# When i execute get LDAPConnection through Swing it hangs

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, ldap, connection

When I run following code through Main method, it works fine but when i try to execute it on click of swing button, it hangs.

Please help

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

public class SimpleLdapAuthentication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String base = "ou=People,dc=objects,dc=com,dc=au";
        String dn = "uid=" + username + "," + base;
        String ldapURL = "ldap://ldap.example.com:389";

        // Setup environment for authenticating

        Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        try {
            DirContext authContext =
            new InitialDirContext(environment);

            // user is authenticated
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {

            // Authentication failed

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it really hang, or just take a long time to come back ?

It's not a good idea to do lots of processing in a Swing event handler, since Swing needs to be responsive to the user. You should delegate long-running actions to another thread.

Comment: I am already using a thread to perform ldap operations. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: No. I think you should publish the code that doesn't work, rather than the code that does

Comment: Here is the code. I have put the above main method code in getT() method in SimpleLdapAuthentication  class. 



    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        SimpleLdapAuthentication sla=new SimpleLdapAuthentication();
        sla.getT();

}

Comment: Rajes, where is the other thread spawned? If I understand correctly, this is Matis generated code. And the jButton1MouseClicked are called from AWT.

Comment: @rajesh - you're just executing this in the event handler, aren't you ?

Comment: correct this is 1 of the codes that I tried... and this is an AWT event listener. But tell what's the problem in executing it this way. If LDAPConnection works with main method why not it work with event listener ? I have seen similar posts on many forum and unable to get the resolution

Answer (score 0):

correct this is 1 of the codes that I tried... and this is an AWT event listener. But tell what's the problem in executing it this way. If LDAPConnection works with main method why not it work with event listener ? I have seen similar posts on many forum and unable to get the resolution

Answer (score 0):

Use an ActionListener instead of MouseListener

```
    btnYourLdapButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            doLdapRequest(ev);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that the code inside the event listener **will not** be run in a separate thread.  It will always run inside the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and for as long as that code is running, no other GUI updates will be possible, and the application will look like it's hanging.  Read [Writing Responsive User Interfaces with Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPSwingThreads.fm.html#1001905) to understand more.  Here's some very rough example code that demonstrates handing a task off to another thread.  I even left a space for you to insert your LDAP call!

```
package examples;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class EDTSeparation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

                final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
                f.add(label);
                f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Do Task") {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // This method will be executed on the EDT
                        label.setText("Working...");

                        // Create a new Thread to do the long-running task so this method can finish quickly.
                        Thread t = new Thread(new LDAPTask(label));
                        t.setDaemon(true);
                        t.start();
                    }
                }));

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class LDAPTask implements Runnable {
        private final JLabel label;

        public LDAPTask(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Use sleep to simulate something taking a long time.
                // Replace this your long-running method call.
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                // If you need to handle GUI components, it must be done on the EDT
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        label.setText("Done.");
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```